# How to call rigify operators?

Tags: python, scripting, rigify, operator

I'd like to run some rigify operators. As you might know, the operators are "unique" for each armature because of their `rig_id`. If I have the `rig_id = "i8fj1rbnfbd76bf5"` then it takes the following syntax to call the operators:

```
bpy.ops.pose.rigify_limb_ik2fk_i8fj1rbnfbd76bf5(prop_bone='thigh_parent.L',
                                                  pole_prop="pole_vector", 
                                                  fk_bones='["thigh_fk.L", "shin_fk.L", "foot_fk.L", "toe.L"]',
                                                  ik_bones='["thigh_ik.L", "MCH-shin_ik.L", "MCH-thigh_ik_target.L"]', 
                                                  ctrl_bones='["thigh_ik.L", "foot_ik.L", "thigh_ik_target.L"]', 
                                                  extra_ctrls='["foot_heel_ik.L", "foot_spin_ik.L"]')

bpy.ops.pose.rigify_limb_ik2fk_i8fj1rbnfbd76bf5(prop_bone='upper_arm_parent.L',
                                                  pole_prop="pole_vector", 
                                                  fk_bones='["upper_arm_fk.L", "forearm_fk.L", "hand_fk.L"]',
                                                  ik_bones='["upper_arm_ik.L", "MCH-forearm_ik.L", "MCH-upper_arm_ik_target.L"]', 
                                                  ctrl_bones= '["upper_arm_ik.L", "hand_ik.L", "upper_arm_ik_target.L"]', 
                                                  extra_ctrls='[]')
```

I was thinking of concatenating the id with the rest of the syntax and converting that into an operator call that I can execute. **Is that possible or what alternatives do I have?**

Comment: Can you explain how you identified the list of arguments needed between the end Brackets ? My rig is different than yours and I'm not sure how to get the list of needed args. Also how did you find out the rigify operators ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Python's exec() or eval() to do this, if the operator is already registered

```py
import bpy
rig_id = "i8fj1rbnfbd76bf5"
op = eval("bpy.ops.pose.rigify_limb_ik2fk_" + rig_id)
# or with exec
# exec("op = bpy.ops.pose.rigify_limb_ik2fk_" + rig_id)

# now you can call op
op(prop_bone='upper_arm_parent.L') # and rest of arguments
```